# Select Data with Count in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel-query-builder

I want to ask how do I select data together with count data.

In this case, I want the user to appear and the number of transactions that he has.

Like this code that I made.

```sql
SELECT "transaction"."user_id",
COUNT(transaction.id) trans_count
FROM transaction 
inner join "users" on "users"."id" = "transaction"."user_id"
GROUP BY user_id
```

The code above successfully selects `user_id` and `trans_count`, but when I am trying to show `users.name`

this error message appears.

> Error in query: ERROR: column "users.name" must appear in the GROUP BY
>   clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 3: "users"."name"

Is it true that I am cannot select other data when I count data or is there a better way ?.

Thank You.

Comment: When several tables are involved, it's good programming practice to qualify all columns, like `"transaction"."user_id"`.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: I don't think there is a need for group by to call others. Thank you very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include `user.name` in the `group by`:

```
SELECT "transaction"."user_id",
"user"."name",
COUNT(transaction.id) trans_count
FROM transaction 
inner join "users" on "users"."id" = "transaction"."user_id"
GROUP BY "transaction"."user_id", "user"."name"
```

Otherwise, when the DBMS tries to combine (`group`) multiple rows into a single row, it doesn't know which `name` value should it pick, which is why it throws the error.

In this case, `user_id` and `user.name` have a one-to-one mapping, so you can simply include `name` in the `group by` clause.

Otherwise you'd have to tell the DBMS how to select one value from the multiple records that are in each group, eg:

`min(user.name)` or `max(user.name)`

```
SELECT "transaction"."user_id",
min("user"."name") user_name,
COUNT(transaction.id) trans_count
FROM transaction 
inner join "users" on "users"."id" = "transaction"."user_id"
GROUP BY "transaction"."user_id"
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation now I am understand, this works now !. :)

Answer (score 0):

When every your using `GROUP BY`
You must be group by all column which is fetching or use Aggregate Functions

Group by (same as @rohitvats)

```
GROUP BY "transaction"."user_id", "user"."name"
```

---- OR ----

Aggregate Functions `MAX()`, `MIN()`

```
SELECT "transaction"."user_id",
MAX("user"."name") as name,
COUNT(transaction.id) trans_count
FROM transaction 
inner join "users" on "users"."id" = "transaction"."user_id"
GROUP BY "transaction"."user_id"
```

Comment: This is very helpful, after this i will learn more about the function you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work *if you aggregated by the `users.id`*:

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_name, COUNT(*) as trans_count
FROM users u JOIN
     transaction t
     ON t.id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

(I removed the double quotes because they clutter the logic and are not necessary to explain what is going on.)

Why?  Presumably, `users.id` is unique (or equivalently the primary key).  Postgres supports aggregating by a unique key in a table and also including unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.  This is an implementation of "functional dependent" aggregations from the SQL standard.

When you use `transactions.user_id`, Postgres does not recognize the functional dependence (even though you might think that the `ON` clause would imply it).  So, your code doesn't work.

The alternative is to add `user_name` to the `GROUP BY` as well.  However, your version almost works if you use the column from the correct table.

Comment: So like that. Thank you for your explanation is very easy to understand. :)